# Displaying Related Table in a Portal in FileMaker

Tags: database-design, filemaker

I have two tables (Locations and LocationsStatus). The first is a list of all locations and the second lists the status of that location. The status is constantly updated and I want to keep a record of status updates over time, so it is necessary to keep a second table.

Now, on a "dashboard" layout I display all locations in a portal (showing table Locations) and I want to display the status from (LocationStatus). However, if I put the field for status in the portal, it shows only the first record in the LocationStatus table related to that particular location. How do I get it to display the LAST related record in the LocationStatus table?

Can I make a portal (using LocationStatus) on top of the portal (for Locations) and sort by date and only display one record only? Or is there a more efficient way to do this? I have tried putting a portal on top of a portal, and it doesn't seem to work. It also doesn't seem very efficient. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional solution to this is to create a dedicated relationship for this purpose, giving that relationship the sort order desired, in this case, a reverse date sort. Once this is done, simply place a portal using your new reverse-sorted relationship on the page and ensure that the fields within the portal also use this same relationship. The desired record will now be displayed first.

Notes: You cannot stack portals in FileMaker, as you've discovered. If you only want to display a single record, you can omit the portal and simply include the fields you want, again wired to the reverse-sorted relationship.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're on the right track for displaying the last LocationStatus in your dashboard portal. The element that you are most likely missing is assigning a sort order to the relationship between the `Location` Table Occurrence and the `LocationStatus` Table Occurrence.

To do that, go you your relationship graph in the Define Database dialog and click on the relationship link. On the `LocationStatus` Table Occurrence side, you'll see a sort order. There you can select a date field on the `LocationStatus` table, such as a Creation Date, and set it to descending order.

Once you have done that, when you pull the `Status` field from that `LocationStatus` Table Occurrence, you will get the last one first.

Of note: FileMaker allows for multiple Table Occurrences for each Table. If you sometimes want the `LocationStatus` in ascending order and sometimes want the `LocationStatus` in descending order, you would create two Table Occurrences of the `LocationStatus` table, each one with a different sort order.